# How to split a string field only if it exists in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to do something like the following

```
db.collection.updateMany(
    {"obj.field": {$exists: true}},
    {$set: {"obj.field": {$split: ["$obj.field", ", "]}}}
);
```

However, it seems `$split` is not supported in update.  How can I split a string field only if it exists?

Answer (score 1):

[$split](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/split/index.html#split-aggregation) is an aggregation operator, not an update operator.

In order to use split in an update, you will need to pass an aggregation pipeline as the second argument to `updateMany`.

Since `$set` is both an update operator and an aggregation pipeline (alias for `$addFields`), that might look like:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
    {"obj.field": {$exists: true}},
    [{$set: {"obj.field": {$split: ["$obj.field", ", "]}}}]
);
```

Note that this require MongoDB 4.2+